# What is Rendering Tier in WPF & Base class of WPF Graphics

Tags: wpf

What is Rendering Tier in WPF.
 & What is Base class of WPF Graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has a good source on rendering tiers: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx), As for WPF Graphics. As far as I know there is no `Graphics` class in WPF and as such no base class. But maybe what you're looking for is in the [Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx)

Otherwise maybe specify your question a bit more.

Hope it helps. - Val